# My app got rejected because of Passkit framework

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval, passbook

So yesterday I got an e-mail from Apple, stating that :
"Your app uses Passbook Passes for irrelevant features, which is not an
approved of Passbook Passes.
Pls reviese your app to remove the Passbook Pass or modify the Pass to
comply
with the approved usages for Passbook Passes."

But I haven't used Passes anywhere, instead apparently I've integrated with an ad network that does use.
Please suggest what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally contact the ad network and ask them if they have encountered this problem before and how other developers can use their ad network in apps published on app store.
Or change ad network.

Comment: I've contacted them, from their side they gave me feedback that this is the first time such problem has been encountered.
Meanwhile, I've also filed a rejection Appeal, stating the Passkit framework being used by a third party(Dunno this will help or not).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Ad Network's SDK? - we may be able to help you find and strip out the PassKit elements

Comment: The link can be found [here](https://www.inmobi.com/AdvancedAdCode/InMobi_iOS_SDK.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I made a rejection Appeal & my app got approved. Thanks everybody for the help!!